# AWS S3 Replication across accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want replicate the content of a bucket in another account.

I've read:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/replication-walkthrough1.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/replication-walkthrough-2.html

I run this as last step, but I have an error.

```sh
$ cat replication.json
{
  "Role": "arn:aws:iam::<ROOT_ACCOUNT_ID>:role/replicationRole",
  "Rules": [
    {
      "Status": "Enabled",
      "Priority": 1,
      "DeleteMarkerReplication": { "Status": "Disabled" },
      "Filter" : { "Prefix": "Tax"},
      "Destination": {
        "Bucket": "arn:aws:s3:::<MY_TARGET_NAME>"
      }
    }
  ]
}

$ aws s3api put-bucket-replication --replication-configuration file://replication.json --bucket <MY_SOURCE_BUKCET> --profile ROOT

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutBucketReplication operation: Access Denied
```

Before this I have done:

- I have enabled versioning on both buckets

```sh
$aws s3api put-bucket-versioning \
--bucket <MY_SOURCE_BUKCET> \
--versioning-configuration Status=Enabled \
--profile ROOT

$aws s3api put-bucket-versioning \
--bucket <MY_TARGET_BUCKET> \
--versioning-configuration Status=Enabled \
--profile TEST
```

- I have created a role with this permisions and policies

```json
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Principal":{
            "Service":"s3.amazonaws.com"
         },
         "Action":"sts:AssumeRole"
      }
   ]
}
```

```json
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "s3:GetObjectVersionForReplication",
            "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl"
         ],
         "Resource":[
            "arn:aws:s3:::<MY_SOURCE_BUCKET>/*"
         ]
      },
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:GetReplicationConfiguration"
         ],
         "Resource":[
            "arn:aws:s3:::<MY_SOURCE_BUCKET>"
         ]
      },
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "s3:ReplicateObject",
            "s3:ReplicateDelete",
            "s3:ReplicateTags",
            "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging"

         ],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::<MY_TARGET_BUCKET>/*"
      }
   ]
}
```

- I have added this policy to the target bucket

```json
{
   "Version":"2008-10-17",
   "Id":"",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Sid":"1",
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Principal":{
            "AWS":"arn:aws:iam::<ROOT_ACCOUNT_ID>:role/replicationRole"
         },
         "Action":["s3:ReplicateObject", "s3:ReplicateDelete"],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::<MY_TARGET_BUCKET>/*"
      },
      {
         "Sid":"2",
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Principal":{
            "AWS":"arn:aws:iam::<ROOT_ACCOUNT_ID>:role/replicationRole"
         },
         "Action":["s3:GetBucketVersioning", "s3:PutBucketVersioning"],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::<MY_TARGET_BUCKET>"
      }
   ]
}
```

The IAM user I'm ussing to perform the tasks (--profile ROOT & --profile TEST) have in both AdministratorAccess

Reading more, I have found this:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_passrole.html
- https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=898000

So I thins I need to add this somewhere...

```json
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "iam:GetRole",
            "iam:PassRole"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::<ROOT_ACCOUNT_ID>:role/replicationRole"
      }
```

But I don't know where (I have tried some options without success)

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: When you run the `aws s3api put-bucket-replication` command, what credentials are you using -- your own IAM User credentials, or are you running the command on an Amazon EC2 instance with an assigned role? The error message suggests that the credentials you are using are not authorized to use the `put-bucket-replication` API call.

Comment: Judging by the error message make sure the user/role you're using (designated by the profile name ROOT in your case) has a policy allowing `PutBucketReplication` action.

Comment: The error msg indicated that you don't have permissions to perform `PutBucketReplication`? What IAM user are you using? Are you sure it has such permissions?

Comment: Hi all, The IAM User I'm using have AdministratorAccess.

Comment: So you are using Admin user from the source or destination account?

Comment: The source account  (Both really, but PutBucketReplication is done by source account). It's a POC. I wanted avoid issues.

Comment: The source account (Both really, but PutBucketReplication is done by source account). It's a POC. I wanted avoid issues.